# HTML Form submitting parameters to function, and function not writing answer to innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

A little exercise I'm working on that uses HTML5, CSS, and JavaScript. The objective has been detailed as:

*exercise on feb 26
- This is an exercise for the partial fulfillment of participation.

- upload the answer on Moodle before 11:00 pm tomorrow
- Late submission will not accepted, but partially completed answers will be awarded partial credit.
- Question - rewrite the javascript script created in the previous exercises. Similar to the previous one, this new version still has two functions named functionA and functionB:
  (1) functionA has one parameter and calculates the total score of a student taking CSC001. The course includes:

  - two quizzes - the full score of each quiz is 10 points, and the weight is 5%.
  - four assignments - the full score of each assignment is 100 points, and the weight is 5%.
  - a midterm exam - the full score is 50, and the weight is 10%.
  - a final exam - the full score is 100, and the weight is 40%.
  - a project - the full score is 25, and the weight is 25%.

    The score of each coursework is stored as one element of an array. When it is called, this array is passed to the functionA via the functionA's parameter and then the functionA calculates the total score of a student.

    After the total score is calculated, functionB is called that will calculate and then return the letter grade (represented by, such as A, B, C, D or F).

  (2) when functionB is called, based on the total grade from step (1), function B calculates and returns the letter grade to functionA. The rules are listed below:

  - A   90% - 100%
  - B   80% - 82%
  - C   70% - 79%
  - D   60% - 69%
  - F   0% - 59%

  (3) call functionA with an array represenring the score of each coursework
  ...

**I wrote some code that is not reporting any error by the browser console, takes my numeric inputs into the fields, wipes them and seems to process, but writes nothing on the page in result. I was hoping someone more skilled in WebDev may give me some insight. Thank you!**

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Feb 26th</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="gray">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var totalScore;

        function functionA(array) {
            if (!(array.length == 9) || !(Array.isArray(array))){
                return false;
            }

            if ((array[0] >= 0 && array[0] <= 10) && (array[1] >= 0 && array[1] <= 10)) {
                var percentage1 = array[0] / 10;
                var percentage2 = array[1] / 10;
                var weightIndividual = 0.05 / 2;
                array[0] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
                array[1] = percentage2 * weightIndividual;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Quizes are out of bounds.');
            }

            if ((array[2] >= 0 && array[2] <= 100) && (array[3] >= 0 && array[3] <= 100) &&
                (array[4] >= 0 && array[4] <= 100) && (array[5] >= 0 && array[5] <= 100)) {
                var percentage1 = array[2] / 100;
                var percentage2 = array[3] / 100;
                var percentage2 = array[4] / 100;
                var percentage2 = array[5] / 100;
                var weightIndividual = 0.05 / 4;
                array[2] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
                array[3] = percentage2 * weightIndividual;
                array[4] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
                array[5] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Assignments are out of bounds.');
            }

            if (array[6] >= 0 && array[6] <= 50) {
                var percentage = array[6] / 50;
                array[6] = percentage * .1;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Midterm is out of bounds.');
            }

            if (array[7] >= 0 && array[7] <= 100) {
                var percentage = array[7] / 100;
                array[7] = percentage * .4;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Final Exam is out of bounds.');
            }

            if (array[8] >= 0 && array[8] <= 25) {
                var percentage = array[8] / 25;
                array[8] = percentage * .25;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Project is out bounds.');
            }

            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                totalScore += array[i];
            }

            functionB();
        }

        function functionB() {
            try{
                switch (totalScore) {
                    case (totalScore >= 90):
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'A';
                        break;
                    case (totalScore < 90 && totalScore >= 80):
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'B';
                        break;
                    case (totalScore < 80 && totalScore >= 70):
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'C';
                        break;
                    case (totalScore < 70 && totalScore >= 60):
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'D';
                        break;
                    case (totalScore < 60):
                        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'F';
                }
            }
            catch(e){
                alert('Grades aren\'t all in yet.');
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <h1>Grade Input</h1>
    <form name="grades" id="grades" onsubmit="return functionA(array[quiz1, quiz2, assignment1, assignment2,
        assignment3, assignment4, midterm, final, project])">
        Enter grade for quiz 1:<br />
        <input id="quiz1" name="quiz1" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for quiz 2:<br />
        <input id="quiz2" name="quiz2" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment1:<br />
        <input id="assignment1" name="assignment1" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment2:<br />
        <input id="assignment2" name="assignment2" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment3:<br />
        <input id="assignment3" name="assignment3" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment4:<br />
        <input id="assignment4" name="assignment4" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for midterm exam:<br />
        <input id="midterm" name="midterm" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for final exam:<br />
        <input id="final" name="final" typ="number"><br />
        Enter grade for project:<br />
        <input id="project" name="project" type="number"><br />
        <button type="submit" form="grades" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p id="result">
        Your: grade is:
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found success with this code here:

```html
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Feb 26th</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="gray">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var totalScore = 0;
        
        function functionA(array) {
            if (!(array.length == 9) || !(Array.isArray(array))){
                return false;
            }
            console.log(array);

            if ((array[0] >= 0 && array[0] <= 10) && (array[1] >= 0 && array[1] <= 10)) {
                var percentage1 = array[0] / 10;
                var percentage2 = array[1] / 10;
                var weightIndividual = 0.05 / 2;
                array[0] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
                array[1] = percentage2 * weightIndividual;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Quizes are out of bounds.');
            }

            if ((array[2] >= 0 && array[2] <= 100) && (array[3] >= 0 && array[3] <= 100) &&
                (array[4] >= 0 && array[4] <= 100) && (array[5] >= 0 && array[5] <= 100)) {
                var percentage1 = array[2] / 100;
                var percentage2 = array[3] / 100;
                var percentage2 = array[4] / 100;
                var percentage2 = array[5] / 100;
                var weightIndividual = 0.05 / 4;
                array[2] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
                array[3] = percentage2 * weightIndividual;
                array[4] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
                array[5] = percentage1 * weightIndividual;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Assignments are out of bounds.');
            }

            if (array[6] >= 0 && array[6] <= 50) {
                var percentage = array[6] / 50;
                array[6] = percentage * .1;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Midterm is out of bounds.');
            }

            if (array[7] >= 0 && array[7] <= 100) {
                var percentage = array[7] / 100;
                array[7] = percentage * .4;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Final Exam is out of bounds.');
            }

            if (array[8] >= 0 && array[8] <= 25) {
                var percentage = array[8] / 25;
                array[8] = percentage * .25;
            }
            else {
                console.log('Project is out bounds.');
            }

            for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                console.log('Adding value of: ' + array[i]);
                if (isNaN(array[i])) { array[i] = 0; };
                totalScore += Number.parseInt(array[i] * 100);
            }

            event.preventDefault();
            functionB();
        }

        function functionB() {
            console.log('xxxxxxxxxxxxxx: ' + totalScore);
            try {
                if (totalScore >= 90) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'A';
                } else if (totalScore < 90 && totalScore >= 80) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'B';
                } else if (totalScore < 80 && totalScore >= 70) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'C';
                } else if (totalScore < 70 && totalScore >= 60) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'D';
                } else if (totalScore < 60) {
                    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'F';
                }
            }
            catch(e){
                alert('Grades aren\'t all in yet.');
            }
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        h1 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>

    <h1>Grade Input</h1>
    <form name="grades" id="grades" onsubmit="return functionA([document.getElementById('quiz1').value, document.getElementById('quiz2').value,
    document.getElementById('assignment1').value, document.getElementById('assignment2').value, document.getElementById('assignment3').value,
    document.getElementById('assignment4').value, document.getElementById('midterm').value, document.getElementById('final').value, document.getElementById('project').value])">
        Enter grade for quiz 1:<br />
        <input id="quiz1" name="quiz1" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for quiz 2:<br />
        <input id="quiz2" name="quiz2" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment1:<br />
        <input id="assignment1" name="assignment1" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment2:<br />
        <input id="assignment2" name="assignment2" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment3:<br />
        <input id="assignment3" name="assignment3" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for assignment4:<br />
        <input id="assignment4" name="assignment4" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for midterm exam:<br />
        <input id="midterm" name="midterm" type="number"><br />
        Enter grade for final exam:<br />
        <input id="final" name="final" typ="number"><br />
        Enter grade for project:<br />
        <input id="project" name="project" type="number"><br />
        <button type="submit" form="grades" value="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <p id="result">
        Your: grade is: 
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```